# Rxjava zip operator filter second Observable by checking data with first Observable android

Tags: android, filter, rx-java, rx-android

I am using `.zip` operator to combine 2 `API calls`

**What I want**

I wanted to get filtered values from `2nd Observable` based on some `ids` from `1st Observable`

**Eg**

`1st Observable` returns data like (sample data)

```
"categories": [
{
            "category": "1",
            "category_name": "Wedding Venues",
            "category_photo_url": "http://www.marriager.com/uploads/album/0463373001465466151-0463467001465466151.jpeg",
            "category_type_id": "1",
```

`2nd Observable` returns data like :

```
"data": [
        {
            "cat_id": "1",
            "category_name": "Wedding Venues",
            "status": "1",
            "order_id": "1",
            "category_type_id": "1"
        },
```

I wanted to filter my 2nd Observable data to only return values that matches  **category_type_id** from 1st Observable

**My Code**

```
Observable obsService = retrofitService.loadService(getSharedPref().getVendorId());
Observable obsCategory = retrofitService.loadCategory();

Observable<ServiceAndCategory> obsCombined = Observable.zip(obsService.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), obsCategory.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), new Func2<ServiceModel, CategoryModel, ServiceAndCategory>() {
            @Override
            public ServiceAndCategory call(ServiceModel serviceModel, CategoryModel categoryModel) {
                return new ServiceAndCategory(serviceModel, categoryModel);
            }
        });
        obsCombined.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

        obsCombined.subscribe(new Subscriber<ServiceAndCategory>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                if (e instanceof UnknownHostException || e instanceof ConnectException) {
                    mPresenter.onNetworkError();
                } else if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    mPresenter.onTimeOutError();
                } else {
                    mPresenter.onServerError();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ServiceAndCategory model) {

                mPresenter.onSuccess(model);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

basically I want to apppy the following logic

```
this.categoryList = combinedModel.categoryModel.getData();
        serviceList = combinedModel.serviceModel.getData().getCategories();

        for (int i = 0; i < serviceList.size(); i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < categoryList.size(); j++) {

                if (!serviceList.get(i).getCategoryTypeId().equals(categoryList.get(j).getCategoryTypeId())) {

                    categoryList.remove(j);

                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply this filtering with reactive approach using a map and a list, first collect all categories to a map, and all services to a list, zip them together, and then filter the services list according to categories map:

```
Observable<HashMap<Integer, CategoryData>> categoriesMapObservable =
        obsCategory
                .flatMapIterable(CategoryModel::getData)
                .reduce(new HashMap<>(),
                        (map, categoryData) -> {
                            map.put(categoryData.getCategoryTypeId(), categoryData);
                            return map;
                        }
                );

Observable<List<ServiceData>> serviceListObservable = obsService
        .map(ServiceModel::getData);

Observable obsCombined =
        Observable.zip(
                categoriesMapObservable
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                serviceListObservable
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                Pair::new
        )
                .flatMap(hashMapListPair -> {
                    HashMap<Integer, CategoryData> categoriesMap = hashMapListPair.first;
                    return Observable.from(hashMapListPair.second)
                            .filter(serviceData -> categoriesMap.containsKey(serviceData.getCategoryTypeId()))
                                .toList();
                    }, (hashMapListPair, serviceDataList) -> new Pair<>(hashMapListPair.first.values(), serviceDataList));
```

the output result depends on you , here I apply at the end a selector of `flatMap()` that will create a Pair of Collection of `CategoryData` and a filtered list of `ServiceData`, you can of course create whatever custom Object you need for that.

I'm not sure you're gaining much from this, it's seems more efficient from complexity perspective, assuming HashMap is O(1), where categories are N, and services are M, you have here N + M (N constructing the map, M iterating the list and querying the map), while your naive implementation will be N x M.

as for code complexity, i'm not sure it worth it, you can apply your logic at the end of the zip for filtering, or use some library that might be doing filter more efficiently.

P.S the `observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(`) is unnecessary so I removed it.

Comment: Avoiding observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()  gave me error of updating view on other thread , that's why I included . Thanks for the answer .

Comment: I didn't explain myself well, I removed this from the flatmap Observable, you need single observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread) before the subscribe for getting the notifications at main thread

Comment: Yeah that's true .